# How to decrypt data in binary file by XOR operator using a given key at specific offset?

Tags: linux, encryption, command-line, xor, compression

I've a binary data files which are encrypted by a simple [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) using a given key at offset `+0x88` (which is `0x80` long), then the data (`+0x108`) is compressed by `lzo1x`.

What would be the most efficient way of decrypting such files?

Preferably by using some command-line utilities (where I can specify the input offsets) or some script (without too much coding)?

Comment: Re-posted from [reverseengineering SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11033/12021), as it seems it's off-topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dd` to extract the data what you need, e.g. (using bash syntax):

```
dd if=foo.dat bs=1 skip=$((0x88)) count=$((0x80)) of=xorkey.bin
dd if=foo.dat bs=1 skip=$((0x108)) of=data1.bin
```

Then convert it using simple Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def str_xor(data, key):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= key[i % len(key)]
    return data

key  = bytearray(open('xorkey.bin', 'rb').read())
data = bytearray(open('data1.bin',  'rb').read())
encoded = str_xor(data, key)
open("data1.bin.xor", "wb").write(encoded)
decoded = str_xor(data, key)
open("data1.bin.xor.xor", "wb").write(decoded)
```

Then install `lzop` tool which offers compression/decompression of the LZO1X algorithms (install via: `apt-get`/`brew` `install lzop`), e.g.:

```
lzop -dc data1.bin.xor > data1.out
```

---

As per [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/how-to-decrypt-data-in-binary-file-by-xor-operator-using-a-given-key-at-specific/11036#comment15329_11036) comment, it's also possible to use PowerShell to get the bytes from a specific block of file and use foreach operator to xor the bytes like this:

```
$foo=(($c=gc .\encrypted.dat -Encoding byte)[0x80..$C.Length]) | %{$_ -bxor 63}
```